# Fastest Method to Append Values to a exported .dat

Tags: list, append, export, wolfram-mathematica

I'm currently trying to write a small export function, however I reached a problem when trying to get the correct export format.
The *LoadElements* functions just generates  *systematic Lists (of 200 paired elements)*.

```
elements = Table[LoadElements[X], {10}];
Export["C:\\Exports\\elements.dat", elements]
```

Like that i get the desired format and the function is fast: For every List a new Line; Example:
{List1Element1, List1Element2...}
{List2Element1, List2Element2...}
The Problem is: With the Export function I cannot Append new valus to the File.

Than I tried to work with streams: However: 1. It is substantially slower than the Export code, 2. I didn't achieve to get the correct Format:

```
Do[
file = OpenAppend["C:\\Exports\\elements.dat", PageWidth -> Infinity];
Write[file, elemnts = Table[LoadElements[X], {2}]];
Close[file];
, {2}];
```

The PageWidth Infinity was needed because otherwise there were Line Breaks, but it gives me the Following Format:
{List1}{List2}
{List3}{List4}
and it is quite slow..

I would be thankfull for an Idea how to be able to easily Append Values to a File with the required Table like format..

---

thank you a lot, it generally works.

Unfortunately, this produces an additional empty line break between every pair of values, any idea why?
So this produces:
 
Resultpair
 

 
Resultpair
 
indstead of:
 
Resultpair
 
Resultpair
 
I mean I can manually get rid of the empty line with another script, however it would be nice to directly get the correct output :)

Comment: You might consider posting this on http://mathematica.stackexchange.com. This dedicated Mathematica site and a sister site of StackOverflow, has become the hangout for many of the experts that served this tag.

Answer (score 3):

You may consider a combination of `ExportString` (since `Export` is already producing the format you desire) and `WriteString`:

```
elements1 = RandomInteger[99, {15, 2, 5}];

elements2 = RandomInteger[99, {15, 3, 3}];

Export["elements.dat", elements1]

file = OpenAppend["elements.dat"];
WriteString[file, "\n", ExportString[elements2, "Table"]]
Close[file]
```

Comment: +1, beat me to it. I'm spending to much time over at [mathematica.se] with your alter ego to get over here that much.

Comment: thank you a lot, it generally works.

Unfortunately, this produces an additional empty line break between every pair of values, any idea why? So this produces:
Resultpair<br>
<br>
Resultpair<br>
indstead of:
Resultpair<br>
Resultpair<br>
<br>
I mean I can manually get rid of the empty line with another script, however it would be nice to directly get the correct output :)

Comment: @PeriodicProgrammer in my test shown above I needed an extra line break to keep things orderly, but it sounds like that is not needed for your application.  Simply remove `"\n", ` so the line reads:  `WriteString[file, ExportString[elements2, "Table"]]` and try again.